# Find a harmonic function u that vanishes on C[0, 2] and satisfies $u(3e^{i\theta}) = 65\cos(2\theta)$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, harmonic-functions, holomorphic-functions

Consider the annulus $G = \{2 \leq |z| \leq  3 \}$ (this is basically a ring with inner radius $2$ and outer radius $3$). Find a harmonic function which vanishes on $C[0, 2] $(this is a circle with center $0$ and radius $2$) and satisfies $u(3\mathrm{e}^{i \theta}) = 65 \cos(2 \theta)$ on $C[0,3].$

Hint: consider functions of the form $z^n$ for suitable $n$.

Since $z^n$ is holomorphic for $n \neq 1$ and therefore harmonic, I've tried $n = 2, 3, 4$. But it doesn't satisfy the condition. I'm not sure if it's worth it to keep trying more $n$s because the expansions get large after this point and it might be a waste of time if it's a big $n$.

How else can I approach this problem? Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's take a look at holomorphic functions of the form
$$f(z)=\sum_{n=-2}^2 a_n z^n\; a_n \in \mathbf{R}. $$

When $|z|=2$ we can write $z=2 \mathrm{e}^{i \theta}$ for some real theta, and then
$$f(2 \exp(i \theta))=4a_{-2} \mathrm{e}^{-2i \theta}-2a_{-1} \mathrm{e}^{-i \theta}+a_0+2a_1 \mathrm{e}^{i \theta}+4 a_2 \mathrm{e}^{2 i \theta} $$
The real part of this is
$$4a_{-2} \cos 2 \theta-2a_{-1} \cos \theta+a_0+2a_1 \cos \theta+4a_2 \cos 2 \theta. $$
In order for it to vanish, we need $$a_{-2}=-a_2 \\ a_{-1}=a_1 \\a_0=0, $$
so that $$f(z)=a_2(z^2-z^{-2})+a_1(z-z^{-1}). $$
Now, for the other boundary condition, substitute $z=3 \exp( i \theta)$ to get
$$\Re f(3 \exp(i \theta)) =a_2(9 \cos 2 \theta-1/9 \cos 2 \theta)+a_1 (3 \cos \theta-1/3 \cos \theta).$$
Can you find the values of constants $a_1,a_2$?

Comment: When it says "vanishes", does it mean only the real part of the function vanishes? because using this method, there is still an imaginary component to the function at r=2

Comment: @ChinmayeeGidwani The question asks for a real-valued, harmonic function. The complex-valued $f(z)$ need not vanish on the boundary of the circle. In fact, if it did, it must be that $f(z) \equiv 0$ due to the identity theorem for holomorphic functions.

Comment: that cleared up a lot of confusion I had, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Negative values of $n$ are allowed. Look at functions of the form

$$\text {Re }\left ( az^2 + \frac{b}{z^2}\right ).$$